# Code runs ten times slower when all I did was move the loop code into a function

Tags: c++, performance

I was running the code below, which essentially does very little. It just adds 2 and four 100 million times and outputs the runtime.

```
#include "time.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void add (){
int tot = 2+4;
}

void main(){
int t = clock();
int count = 0;
while(count<100000000){
    int tot = 2+4;
    count++;
}
cout <<endl<< "runtime = " << fixed <<(double) (clock() - t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<"s" << endl;
```

}

But I was interested to see the time difference when doing the exact same thing but calling a function. So I replaced the line "int tot = 2+4" with "add()".

I was expecting the second runtime to be slightly longer but was a lot longer. First implementation = `.3s` and second implementation = `3s`.

I understand calling the function requires using the stack to store the return address and  store local data. But it must be doing a lot **more** then this?

Would be great if someone could explain to me what exactly causes the big difference in runtime or maybe I am doing something silly.

Comment: Why don't you just compare the assembly output of the compilation yourself? Also, try it again with optimizations turned on!

Comment: You do realize the compiler will (almost certainly) optimize away the addition to a 6 at compile-time?

Comment: Your measurements are probably meaningless. Compiler can throw away all unused code that has no side effects, following *as-if* rule, inline the function calls, unroll loops, etc. It all depends on how good your compiler is at optimization.

Comment: And just as expected, the run time of your both versions is ... 0 sec, even if you boost a loop count to 1 billion. Surprised? Shouldn't be: http://ideone.com/dNYfv

Comment: @Gene: this is assuming optimizations, maybe he's not using g++ which by default does this or he's not giving us the original code he used which my actually use tot.

Comment: @Kerrek a lot of people don't understand assembly.

Comment: Turn on optimizations (`-O3` in GCC). Without optimizations turned on, the compiler won't even try to emit fast code - instead, it will add a bunch of additional instructions that make debugging easier, but slow down many common operations. Function calls in particular are dramatically slower with `-O0` than `-O3`.

Comment: What compiler and what build settings? The costs of a function call are highly dependent on both.

It's fairly obvious that you are using no optimizations, but knowing what compiler (and CPU) would still be interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned already by Seth, inline functions would probably get optimized.

In the 1st case (with basic optimizations on) most likely instead of constantly adding those 2 numbers it will resolve 2 + 4 to 6 and simply just do a simple

```
mov eax, 6 ;eax is just an example here or
mov tot_addr, 6 ; mem->mem mov
```

In the 2nd case since it is a function call the system has to

```
push 4 ;assuming 4 byte ints
push 4 ;wrote 2 to be clear that you have to push both variables
call add
```

or something along these lines. As the call stack needs to be created for that function (ommitted return value push and such for simplicity). Once this function returns the stack pointer needs to be moved back previous to that first push and then the RET will set the instruction pointer back. As you can see this is more expensive than doing a simple

```
mov eax, 4
add eax, 2
```

which is likely to be the case if you were doing just a simple (non optimized add)

EDIT: Here's some more information about in-lining the function. When you inline the function it simply takes whatever functionality the function itself would do and places the instructions directly where it is reference instead of doing a CALL instruction and setting up a function call directly. For instance instead of

```
mov eax, 4
mov ecx, 2
push 4 ; size for return value
push eax
push ecx
call add
```

You will end up with

```
mov eax, 4
mov exc, 2
add eax, ecx
```

In code terms:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 2;
int res = add(a, b);
```

would become

```
int a = 4;
int b = 2;
int res = a + b;
```

assuming you inline the add function.

Comment: not really, compiler doesn't need to do all these micro-optimizations, it simply throws away all unused code, generating a single line for the whole program: `return 0;`

Comment: @Gene: But the OP is talking about function performance and use of functions vs inline functionality. I know the compiler doesn't care about unused code and simply throws it away but why would the whole program just become return 0;

Comment: @Gene: nevermind I read the code a little more and see that since the loop does "nothing"  it pretty much just goes away.

Answer (score 2):

Relative to doing other things, function calls are very expensive (more expensive than you think), for just the reason you mention. Try declaring your function `inline` and/or enabling optimisations to get back the performance.

Answer (score 0):

A function call can indeed cause a lot more work for the CPU than simply pushing a return address and parameters.

On some CPUs, you'll get a pipeline stall.  Maybe even an i-cache miss while reading the next instruction.  These could easily cause even more than the 10x slowdown you've noted.

That's why compilers go to great lengths to optimize away function calls.

Comment: You are more likely to incur a page fault from a function call than from inline functionality as well. Cache misses can happen as well (next instruction doesn't necessarily have good locality which also explains the faults). I didn't go into this much detail as assembly is probably already more than the OP bargained for.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: I mentioned cache misses (a page fault is a form of cache miss), and yes lack of locality is the reason for the miss.